# Mini UPS 5V Module

Tags: arduino, battery-charging, raspberry-pi, charging, ups

I've bought a mini 5V UPS board that I need to coninously power a Raspberry pi. In the image description I see that there are 2 D+ and 1 D- PINS INPUT (wall supply, for example), 2 D+ and 2 D- pins BATTERY, 2 D+ and 2 D- pins LOAD. Why there are more than one pin for each purpose? Do I need some Arduino cables to use this module? I've posted images here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't look a gift horse in the mouth.

Comment: If those 2 pins are shorted together on the board, you don't need to use both (as long as the wires are not too thin or too long), you can just use 1 pin and 1 wire for those. They use 2 either to match connections on a specific board, or to reduce voltage drop and power loss of a single wire.

Comment: Seems like it makes it easier to also connect multiple sources to each.

Comment: Does arduino jumper wires are fine  ? I need about 2A...

Comment: What are *arduino jumper wires*?

Comment: these https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61usKAShCAL._AC_SL1000_.jpg